# SurfaceView Zoom IN and OUT functionality using Custom Camera

Tags: android, zooming, surfaceview

I have written code to work with Custom Camera and for this I am using SurfaceView, now i want to know what if i need to implement Zoom IN and OUT functionality, I never worked on this kind of app.

My code, which i used to create Custom Camera, see below:

**MainActivity.java:-**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SurfaceView preview=null;   
    private SurfaceHolder previewHolder=null;   
    public Camera camera ;    
    private boolean inPreview=false;   
    ImageButton btnCapture;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

            preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);     
            previewHolder=preview.getHolder();    
            previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);    
            previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
            previewHolder.setFixedSize(getWindow().getWindowManager()     
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), getWindow().getWindowManager() 
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()); 

      btnCapture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);

      btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Capture Image(s)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
          }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {  
        super.onResume();   
        camera=Camera.open(); 
    }  

    @Override   
    public void onPause() {  
        super.onPause();  
        if (inPreview) {  
            camera.stopPreview();   }   
        camera.release();   
        camera=null;   
        inPreview=false;         
    }   


    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,Camera.Parameters parameters){   
        Camera.Size result=null;   
        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) 
        {   
            if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height)
            {
                if (result==null) {  
                    result=size;   
                }   else {  
                    int resultArea=result.width*result.height; 
                    int newArea=size.width*size.height;  
                    if (newArea>resultArea) {   
                        result=size;   
                    }  
                }   
            }   
        }   
        return(result);   
    }

    SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {     
            try {        
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder); 
            }   catch (Throwable t) {   
                Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
                  "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
            }     
        }      

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format, int width,int height) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();       
            Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height,                                           
                    parameters);       
            if (size!=null) {      
                parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);       
                camera.startPreview();       
                inPreview=true;       
            }     
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }   
    };       
}
```

**activity_main.xml:-**

```
<RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_background" >

    <android.view.SurfaceView   
        android:id="@+id/surface"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/capture"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is the sample code for zoom functionality .Please try if it can help you:

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {

private FrameLayout pCameraLayout = null; // this layout contains surfaceview
private ZoomControls zoomControls ;
Camera mCamera=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        enableZoom();
    }   

    private void enableZoom() {
        zoomControls = new ZoomControls(this);
        zoomControls.setIsZoomInEnabled(true);
        zoomControls.setIsZoomOutEnabled(true);
        zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                zoomCamera(false);

            }
        });
        zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                zoomCamera(true);
            }
        });
        pCameraLayout.addView(zoomControls);
    }

    /** 
     * Enables zoom feature in native camera .  Called from listener of the view 
     * used for zoom in  and zoom out.
     * 
     * 
     * @param zoomInOrOut  "false" for zoom in and "true" for zoom out
     */
    public void zoomCamera(boolean zoomInOrOut) {
        if(mCamera!=null) {
            Parameters parameter = mCamera.getParameters();

            if(parameter.isZoomSupported()) {
                int MAX_ZOOM = parameter.getMaxZoom();
                int currnetZoom = parameter.getZoom();
                    if(zoomInOrOut && (currnetZoom <MAX_ZOOM && currnetZoom >=0)) {
                        parameter.setZoom(++currnetZoom);
                    }
                    else if(!zoomInOrOut && (currnetZoom <=MAX_ZOOM && currnetZoom >0)) {
                    parameter.setZoom(--currnetZoom);
                    }
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(context, "Zoom Not Avaliable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mCamera.setParameters(parameter);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

I found a way by using several links, it works for me, and finally i have added code into my **surfaceChanged(...)**, my complete **surfaceChanged(..) code** looks like, below:

**declare variable** of int datatype named ***currentZoomLevel*** and assign ***0*** as initial value,

```
  int currentZoomLevel = 0;
```

**Code:-**

```
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format, int width,int height) {
            params = camera.getParameters();       
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
            Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height,                                           
                    params);       
            if (size!=null) {      
                params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                camera.setParameters(params);       
                camera.startPreview();       
                inPreview=true;   
                ZoomControls zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls);

                if (params.isZoomSupported()) {
                    final int maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
                    Log.i("max ZOOM ", "is " + maxZoomLevel);
                    zoomControls.setIsZoomInEnabled(true);
                    zoomControls.setIsZoomOutEnabled(true);

                    zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(View v){
                            if(currentZoomLevel < maxZoomLevel){
                                currentZoomLevel++;
                                //mCamera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                                params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                                camera.setParameters(params);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(View v){
                            if(currentZoomLevel > 0){
                                currentZoomLevel--;
                                params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                                camera.setParameters(params);
                            }
                        }
                    });    
                }
                else
                    zoomControls.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }     
            }
```

**Xml:-**

```
<ZoomControls
    android:id="@+id/zoomControls"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

***I am placing my answer, just for more clearity and for viewers future use..***