# GLSurfaceView Zoom(PINCH ZOOM)

Tags: android, pinchzoom, glsurfaceview

```
<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
</android.opengl.GLSurfaceView>
```

Do i have to crate custom GLSurfaceView class to apply pinch zoom  like we do for imageview ?

i ref [zoom out in OpenGL in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114462/zoom-out-in-opengl-in-android) this but didnt got it . it would be better if any one help me out

Comment: What is unclear in the reference post for you?

Comment: where i have to use private class ScaleDetectorListener implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener .do i have to create GLSurfaceView custom class?

Answer (score 0):

Steps would be extending `GLSurfaceView` and add following in your custom class:

```
ScaleGestureDetector mDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(),
        new ScaleDetectorListener());

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Then follow the post [zoom out in OpenGL in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114462/zoom-out-in-opengl-in-android) about setting the scale for the `GLSurfaceView`

Comment: i am using through xml thats the problem

Comment: It's not a problem, read this how to create a custom view http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html