# Changing view size in run-time efficiently

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-custom-view

I've a surfaceview to do some drawing stuff. My view supports zoom in/out feature. Now when user zoom in/out by finger gesture, I want to resize the surfaceview, I've tried resizing by changing surfaceview's layout params. Although this works, but it's slow, and while doing the resize work, I see some big jumps (lags), Which is no usable. Here, I want to know how can I resize the surfaceview efficiently (without that jump)?

Here sniped of my view structure,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomMenu"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <MySurfaceView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout> ...
```

And the params changing code,

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = surface.getLayoutParams();
params.height = (int) (750*factor);
surface.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`TextureView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html)?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21282056/4069985

Answer (score 0):

Well in the end I found a method of surfaceHolder to set the canvas size fixed,

```
    holder.setFixedSize(canvasW, canvasH);
```

With this method I'm able to resize layout with layout params, without any kind of lagging. Here, I need to know the canvas size before setting it up, so I added my SurfaceView from Java code with predefined size and it's working smoothly.

**I'm not still sure, why setting up canvas fixed size done the trick. You are welcome to explain a bit (may be edit this answer).

Comment: Can you please add more details how did you do it ? I am facing the same problem when resizing a SurfaceView with changing layout lags.

Comment: when initializing the surfaceHolder set it's size fixed with above method.