# How to use android camera zoom on my custom camera?

Tags: android, xamarin, camera, zooming

I did my job on making custom camera app with using xamarin. I rendered camera and now I have to implement zoom function. However, I don't know how to do it. I searched and found there is startSmoothZoom(int ). But how can I use this? Is there any example? I call that function when device recognize pinch gesture. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280196/surfaceview-zoom-in-and-out-functionality-using-custom-camera), and next time use searcg

Comment: Hi, based on your custom Camera, I think you have already created a **View** which extends `SurfaceView`, and then just put my answer's code to the **View**

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot to do it, now I did. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private float oldDist = 1f;//to caculate Zoom in/out
    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.PointerCount == 1) {
        }
        switch (e.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                oldDist = getFingerSpacing(e);
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                float newDist = getFingerSpacing(e);
                if (newDist > oldDist) {
                    //mCamera is your Camera which used to take picture, it should already exit in your custom Camera
                    handleZoom(true, mCamera);
                } else if (newDist<oldDist) {
                    handleZoom(false, mCamera);
        }
                oldDist = newDist;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //get fingers's distance
    private static float getFingerSpacing(MotionEvent e)
    {
        float x = e.GetX(0) - e.GetX(1);
        float y = e.GetY(0) - e.GetY(1);
        return (float)Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }
    //Zoom
    private void handleZoom(Boolean isZoomIn, Camera camera)
    {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();
        if (parameters.IsZoomSupported) {
            int maxZoom = parameters.MaxZoom;
            int zoom = parameters.Zoom;
            if (isZoomIn && zoom < maxZoom)
            {
                zoom++;
            }
            else if (zoom > 0)
            {
                zoom--;
            }
            parameters.Zoom=zoom;
            camera.SetParameters(parameters);
        } else {
            Android.Util.Log.Error("lv", "zoom not supported");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did my job with other way, but this is also great. Thank you for helping :)